# enum comparison in if statement never true in c

Tags: c, if-statement, enums

I am developing a program in ansi C, and I have some issues.
I have an `enum` along the lines of

```
enum day
{
    Monday = 'M',
    Tuesday = 'T',
    Wednesday = 'W'
}
```

and a `2d array` of `days`

```
typedef enum day availDays[numOfWeeks][daysOfWeek];
memset(theArray, Monday, sizeof(theArray));
```

later used in an if statement like this:

```
if ( theArray[0][0] == Monday )
    { foo statements; }
```

but that condition never evaluates to `true` even if every element of the array is `Monday`, any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that **`sizeof(enum day) != 1`**. So you can't use `memset`.

This happens because although you set every enum value to a `char`, the underlying type of the enum is not `char`. It is (most likely) `int`.

This is the reason why `memset` doesn't work. It sets each byte of the element to 'M'. As such each element will be a "concatenation" of the 4 bytes of value 'M'.

Assuming little endian, ASCII char encoding (`'M'` is `0x4D`) and `sizeof(int) 4`, the array should look like this in memmory:

```
0x4D0000004D000000...
```

`memset` sets it to:

```
0x4D4D4D4D...
```

The only solution is to loop over the array and set each element individually

```
for (i...)
    for (j...)
        theArray[i][j] = Monday;
```

Moral of the story: use `memset` only for `char` buffers. `char` is the only type mandated by standard to have exactly size 1.

---

Although the question is about `C`, it is good to know for whoever needs this in `C++`, that since `C++11` you can specify the underlying type of an `enum`:

```
enum Day : char {
   ...
};

sizeof(Day) == 1; // true
```