# Why isn't memset assigning 1?

Tags: c++, c, memset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int color[1001][1001];

int main() {
    int i, j;
    memset(color, 1, sizeof(color[0][0]) * 2 * 2);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", color[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
16843009 16843009 16843009 16843009 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Why isn't it assigning 1? Why didn't it print 1 instead of 16843009 ? How can i assign integer 1?

But if i write `memset(color, 0, sizeof(color[0][0]) * 2 * 2);` Then the output:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Why is this?

Any answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cut'n'paste from the manual page - "memset - fill memory with a constant byte "

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34691640/2805305

Comment: Because you didn't read the docs of the function you're using. ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) :

> ```
> #include <string.h>
> void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
> ```
>
> The `memset()` function fills **the first `n` bytes** of the memory area pointed to by `s` with the constant byte `c`.

Therefore, `memset` can't be used to initialize `int` array with `1` because if `int` is represented by 4 bytes, then it will initialize each bytes with `1`.
`16843009` is equivalent to `0x01010101`. Each of 4 bytes are initialized with `01`.
Using `memset`, an array of `int` can only be initialised with `0` or `-1` because `0` and `-1` both have all bits `0` and `1` respectively in *two's complement binary representation* regardless of the size of `int` data type.

Comment: But if i write `memset(color, 0, sizeof(color[0][0]) * 2 * 2);` Then the output is zero. Why? I have edited the original question.

Comment: @shibly because an integer where all the individual bytes are zero, is also the value zero  of that integer. (And since your array is declared at file scope (A "global" variable), the entire array is anyway initialized with zero values)

Comment: @nos, 0x00000000 = null character(ascii), isn't it?

Comment: @shibly If you interpret the value as ascii, yes. Though normally you'd use a char to represent ascii values.

Comment: @shibly; I already explained it in the answer. Note that `char` is of only `1` byte. So `0x00` represents a null character in hexadecimal.

Comment: @haccks `16843009` is equivalent to `0x01010101` I'm wondering why you don't take the value of `Binary` but take the number of `hexadecimal 16843009 = 0x01010101` ?

Comment: @Oosutsuke; Sorry, I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 15):

Because `memset` sets *each byte* to `1`.

So if `int` is four bytes (32 bits, what it most commonly is) then you set each element to `0x01010101`.

Read more [in this `memset` reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

---

For a more C++-ish solution I suggest using [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
std::fill(&color[0][0], &color[0][0] + sizeof(color) / sizeof(color[0][0]), 1);
```

That will set all elements to `1`.

---

A third option is to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, and its [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) member function:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 1001>, 1001> color;
...
for (auto& inner : color)
{
    inner.fill(1);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect use of fill.  The iterator you pass as the first argument must have its value writable by dereferencing it, however dereferencing `color` gives another array. This causes a compilation error.  Also `color + sizeof(color)/sizeof(color[0][0])` causes undefined behaviour by forming an out-of-bounds pointer.

Comment: @M.M I always thought a pointer right behind the last element is well-defined, only dereferencing it is not. Iterators work this way, AFAIK.

Comment: @M.M Just for confirmation, it should be `std::fill(&color[0][0], &color[0][0] + sizeof(color) / sizeof(color[0][0]), 1);`, is it right?

Comment: @cad , Yes, forming pointer to one-past-the-last element is explicitely allowed.

Comment: @cad That's true . `sizeof(color)/sizeof(color[0])` would lead to such a pointer. However the actual code divides by a smaller quantity than `sizeof(color[0])`.

Comment: @songyuanyao arguably that version also breaks the rule about `+` adding to the same array, because it goes off the end of `color[0]`.  I would write `(int *)&color, (int *)&color + sizeof(color)/sizeof(int)` . Actually I would avoid all this entirely by using either a 1-d array, or a nested ranged-based `for`

Comment: @M.M `&color[0][0]` is always equivalent with `(int *)&color`, isn't it? Might break in some cases?

Comment: @songyuanyao Both result in the same address, but they are not really the same and should not be treated as such. See e.g. [this recent answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771298/pointer-and-address-to-that-pointer-lead-to-the-same-thing/35771465#35771465) for details.

Comment: But if i write `memset(color, 0, sizeof(color[0][0]) * 2 * 2);` Then the output is zero. Why? I have edited the original question.

Comment: @M.M  & JoachimPileborg, I see, thanks.

Comment: @shibly Because then you initialize each byte to zero, i.e. an `int` would be `0x00000000`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, zero = null? The value of null = zero.

Comment: @shibly A null pointer doesn't *have* to be equal to zero. If needed, the compiler will translate `0` to the correct null-pointer value when dealing with pointers. To be safe use `0` for the actual *value* zero, and `nullptr` for pointers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, not null pointer, null character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, 0x00000000 = null character(ascii), isn't it?

Comment: @shibly Ah then yes, the null *character* is zero. And no, a single character is usually only a single byte, so only `0x00` (or `'\0'`)

Answer (score 7):

`memset()` will write the specified value to *every byte* in the range, so if `int` is 4-byte long, the value will be `0x01010101`, not `1`.

To assign integer 1, assign integer 1.

```
for (i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(color)/sizeof(*color)); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (int)(sizeof(color[i])/sizeof(*color[i])); j++) {
        color[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`memset()` is setting your memory 8-Bit aligned to the value you chose, which is `1`. But for your array `color[][]` you declared the 32-Bit datatype `int`, which has four bytes. So what `memset()` does is to set each of this four bytes to the value `1`.

This also explains your result: `16843009d = 0x01010101`.

If you have a look at your memory:

`memset()` to `1`:

```
//.color[0][0].||..color[0][1]...||..color[0][2]...||..color[0][3]..
01  01  01  01    01  01  01  01    01  01  01  01    01  01  01  01
//.color[1][0].||..color[1][1]...||..color[1][2]...||..color[1][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00
//.color[2][0].||..color[2][1]...||..color[2][2]...||..color[2][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00 
//.color[3][0].||..color[3][1]...||..color[3][2]...||..color[3][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00
```

`memset()` to `0`:

```
//.color[0][0].||..color[0][1]...||..color[0][2]...||..color[0][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00
//.color[1][0].||..color[1][1]...||..color[1][2]...||..color[1][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00
//.color[2][0].||..color[2][1]...||..color[2][2]...||..color[2][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00 
//.color[3][0].||..color[3][1]...||..color[3][2]...||..color[3][3]..
00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00    00  00  00  00
```

If you are calling `memset()` with the value `0` then you get a 32 Bit `int` `value = 0x00000000 = 0d`.

#### Note:

If you want to set your whole array to a value use the following line:

```
memset(color, 1, sizeof(color));
```

Then your array looks the following:

```
1010101 1010101 1010101 1010101 
1010101 1010101 1010101 1010101 
1010101 1010101 1010101 1010101 
1010101 1010101 1010101 1010101
```

View the code [here[^]](http://ideone.com/iKm54o).

Comment: But if i write `memset(color, 0, sizeof(color[0][0]) * 2 * 2);` Then the output is zero. Why? I have edited the original question.